# Special chars like Umlaute are not saved correctly in android sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, character-encoding, special-characters

I can't save special characters like umlaute (e.g. Ä,Ü,ö, etc.) using sqlite in Android. Typing "ä" results in "\u00E4".

I've already tried following code to save a string in database, but didn't help:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

String content = comment.getContent().toString();
byte[] chars = content.getBytes("UTF-8");
String utf8Content = new String(chars, "UTF-8");

values.put(DBHandler.CONTENT,utf8Content);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to put after converting it to UTF-8, Is there any exception showing if you put `content` directly to `values.put` ?

Comment: There's no exception.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: There's no error, only the database doesn't save the string correctly with its umlauts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know `values.put` accepts those characters like `"ä"`. For some reason It can be saved in `SQLite` after converting that into Unicode character like `"\u00E4"`. Simply in such case Save it in `SQLite` as it is and convert `"\u00E4"` again into `"ä"` when retrieving that data. Here is the method that returns those characters converting from Unicode characters.

```
public String getCharacterFromUnicode (String unicodeChar){    
    String returnString = null
    try {
        byte[] utf8 = unicodeChar.getBytes("UTF-8");
       returnString = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
    }catch (Exception ex){    
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Which returns your `"\u00E4"` to `"ä"`.

**UPDATE :**

If you are not sure which parts is converted to Unicode then use [Apache commons-lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library to escape those,

```
myString = org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(myString);
```

Comment: This method is a NO-OP. Encoding a string in UTF-8 and then decoding it again as UTF-8 does not change the string at all.

Comment: @JohannesN. Method didn't work or value not stored in SQLite as unicode ?

Comment: how can I make sure that the value is stored as unicode? Can you give a code sample, please?

Comment: @JohannesN. Simply you can check like  `if(cursor.getString(COLUMN_INDEX).startsWith("\u")){---}`

Comment: But how can special signs be inserted without checks and explicit handling as the signs that were entered by the user?

Comment: You already told that  `"ä" ` signs inserted into SQLite as ` \u00E4 `

Comment: Yes, I did, but how can I prevent that "ä" won't be inserted as a unicode sign without special checks you described above?

Comment: I highly suggest you not to look after that, like why it's inserted in unicode format. How ever it saves let it save. But focus more on the result you get after that. So see my update that will help you escape all those kind of unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SQLiteDatabase.execSQL("PRAGMA ENCODING=UTF-8;");
```

or equivalent encoding you required

Comment: Per default sqlite has UTF-8 as encoding charset, hasn't it?

Comment: @JohannesN. yea... thanks for info... tell me which all terminals you tried your above code?? terminal as in mobile phones

Comment: I only tested on mobile phone (Samsung SII).

Comment: try some other device if possible!!

Comment: your approach above unfortunately didn't work for me.